# Different result in rails console and in puts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use `puts(@participantt = Participant.where(id: 1))` then in the console I get

```
  Participant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/interviews_controller.rb:119:in `puts'
#<Participant:0x000000000c778bf0>
```

But if I type `@participantt = Participant.where(id: 1)` in rails console then I get

```
  Participant Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Participant id: 1, name: "Ram", email: "Ram@g.com", created_at: "2020-05-08 08:19:00", updated_at: "2020-05-08 08:19:00">]>
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts` calls `to_s` on before printing result of expression(which will be an object) passed to it. It generally prints class name with it's object id.

Here, result of `@participant = Participant.where(id: 1)` is the Participant with id and get stored in instance variable `@participant`

Passing `@participant` to `puts` will first call `@participant.to_s` before printing it.

In case of just `@participant = Participant.where(id: 1)`, the console shows the result which is typical REPL utility does. And if you do `puts @participant` there after then you will again get same as what you get with `puts` in you question.

Comment: Then how to print properly in `puts`

Comment: you can use `p` method or use `puts object.inspect`

Comment: Thanks, I got it

Comment: Can you also please tell me how can I access email from @participantt

Comment: `@participant.email` super simple. I would suggest you learn basic of Ruby . StackOveflow won't help you in long run.

Comment: I tried that both in console and in `p` but it is not giving the output

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):7
  Participant Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<Participant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000000ae89a68>)